# How can I deploy my CMDBuild environment?

Tags: installation, failed-installation, jelastic, cmdb

I tried to complete this tutorial : https://docs.jelastic.com/cmdbuild 
but when I have to do the first step to install the aplication, I tried to 'open in browser' but it shows a white page all time and I can finish the installation.

Comment: What do the logs say? https://docs.jelastic.com/statistic-log-cloud-hosting-in-jelastic

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy CMDBuild 2.4.0 version you need to use Tomcat8 on Java8 application server. 
You still can use this [article](https://docs.jelastic.com/cmdbuild) as a guide, the only thing you need to change is create environment with Tomcat8 on Java8 on the first step of this guide.

[image: dashboard, creating environment]

[image]

Also we can suggest you to use docker containers to install CMDBuild.
You will find a lot of useful information by following this [link](https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-management) about how to create and use docker containers within Jelastic environment.

Have a nice day!